# Custom login with Spring Security and OAuth2

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, thymeleaf, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to customize login behavior in my Spring Boot app.

The security configuration of my app is as follows:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Import(SecurityProblemSupport.class)

public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  private final CustomAuth2UserService customAuth2UserService;

  public SecurityConfiguration(CustomAuth2UserService customAuth2UserService) {
    this.customAuth2UserService = customAuth2UserService;
    
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
    web.ignoring()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
        .antMatchers("/app/**/*.{js,html}")
        .antMatchers("/bundle.js")
        .antMatchers("/slds-icons/**")
        .antMatchers("/assets/**")
        .antMatchers("/i18n/**")
        .antMatchers("/content/**")
        .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/**")
        .antMatchers("/swagger-resources")
        .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs")
        .antMatchers("/api/redirectToHome")
        .antMatchers("/test/**");
  }

  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    
    RequestMatcher csrfRequestMatcher = new RequestMatcher() {
      private RegexRequestMatcher requestMatcher =
          new RegexRequestMatcher("/api/", null);

      @Override
      public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return requestMatcher.matches(request);
      }
    };

    http.csrf()
        .requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(csrfRequestMatcher)
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/oauth2login").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/manage/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/entry-point").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/oauth2/*").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/auth-info").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
        .antMatchers("/management/health").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/management/info").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/management/prometheus").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/management/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .oauth2Login().loginPage("/oauth2login")
        .defaultSuccessUri("/")
        .userInfoEndpoint()
        .userService(customOAuth2UserService);
    http.cors().disable();
  }
}
```

The custom OAuth2 user service is as follows:

```
@Component
public class CustomOAuth2UserService extends DefaultOAuth2UserService {

  private UserRepository userRepository;
  private RoleUserEmailMapRepository roleUserEmailMapRepository;

  ...

  @Override
  public OAuth2User loadUser(OAuth2UserRequest userRequest)  {
    DefaultOAuth2User oAuth2User = (DefaultOAuth2User) super.loadUser(userRequest);
    Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>(oAuth2User.getAuthorities());
    Map<String, Object> attributes = oAuth2User.getAttributes();
    ...
  }
}
```

The OAuth controller is as follows:

```
@Controller
public class OAuthController {

  private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OAuthController.class);

  @GetMapping("/oauth2login")
  public String signIn(Model model) {
    log.info("Sign in!!");
    model.addAttribute("email",
        "");
    return "first-page";
  }
}
```

`first-page.html` is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Enter email</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container my-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <form th:action="@{/redirect-to-auth-provider}" method="post">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="email" class="col-form-label">Email id</label>
                        <input type="text" th:value="${email}" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 mt-5">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

OAuth client config properties are as follows:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.abc-auth.client-id=123456
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.abc-auth.client-name=Auth Server
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.abc-auth.scope=api
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.abc-auth.provider=abc-auth
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.abc-auth.client-authentication-method=basic
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.abc-auth.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
myapp.oauth2.path=https://abc-auth.com/services/oauth2/
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.abc-auth.token-uri=${myapp.oauth2.path}token
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.abc-auth.authorization-uri=${myapp.oauth2.path}authorize
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.abc-auth.user-info-uri=${myapp.oauth2.path}userinfo
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.abc-auth.user-name-attribute=name
```

The Auth provider controller is as follows:

```
@Controller
public class AuthProviderController {

  private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthProviderController.class);

  @Autowired
  private OAuth2ClientProperties properties;

  Map<String, String> oauth2AuthenticationUrls
      = new HashMap<>();

  @RequestMapping(value = "/redirect-to-auth-provider", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public ModelANdView entryPoint(String email) {
    log.info("EMAIL RECEIVED AS PART OF REQUEST PARAM = " + email);
    List<ClientRegistration> clientRegistrations = new ArrayList<>(
        OAuth2ClientPropertiesRegistrationAdapter.getClientRegistrations(properties).values());

    String authorizationRequestBaseUri
        = "oauth2/authorization/";
    String tenantName = email.split("@")[1];
    log.info("DERIVED TENANT NAME = " + tenantName);
    clientRegistrations.forEach(registration ->      //FOR TESTING, HARD-CODED THE VALUES
        oauth2AuthenticationUrls.put("abc.com",
            authorizationRequestBaseUri + "abc-auth"));

    return new ModelAndView("redirect:" + oauth2AuthenticationUrls.get("salesforce.com"));
  }
}
```

Now while I am browsing the end-point of my app: `https://localhost:4060`(existing end-point of my app), it's successfully redirecting to `https://localhost:4060/oauth2login`, where I am able to enter email id.

On submit of email id, in the browser network tab, I am seeing: `/redirect-to-auth-provider` end-point getting invoked, and the following three sequences of calls are happening as expected:

```
1. https://localhost:4060/oauth2/authorization/abc-auth
2. https://abc-auth.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=123456&scope=api&state=qKPaLcuCp5vtXPlZDQMFKA7Qe4wLApFKtaPB9HOIN0M=&redirect_uri=https://localhost:4060/oauth2
3. https://localhost:4060/oauth2?code=abcdef&state=qKPaLcuCp5vtXPlZDQMFKA7Qe4wLApFKtaPB9HOIN0M=
```

But, at the end of this call chain, after successful authentication, it's again redirecting to the same page: `https://localhost:4060/oauth2login`. I want the behavior as, the user gets authenticated properly and after successful authentication, the user should no longer get redirected to `https://localhost:4060/oauth2login`.

To my surprise, it's working perfectly fine, when I am NOT customizing the login behavior. Then post-authentication, the user is redirected to the home page i.e. `https://localhost:4060`, and able to properly use the app.

I am not able to figure out what I am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in an earlier comment, I recommend focusing on a minimal example of your specific problem, instead of a complex application. It helps to learn those basics in small pieces, and it helps us help you more easily if you have a minimal example.

The concept in play here is customizing the `redirect_uri`. You'll want to thoroughly review the entire section of the docs on [OAuth2 Login](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/login/advanced.html), specifically the section on the [Redirection Endpoint](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/login/advanced.html#oauth2login-advanced-redirection-endpoint).

It's difficult to tell, but it looks as though you have somehow customized the `redirect_uri` for the abc-auth client. In order to make this work, you'll need to instruct the `OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter` to use your customized `redirect_uri`, as in the following example:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuth2LoginSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .oauth2Login(oauth2 -> oauth2
                .redirectionEndpoint(redirection -> redirection
                    .baseUri("/oauth2/*")
                    ...
                )
            );
    }
}
```

Note, the actual endpoint for `abc-auth` will be `/oauth2/abc-auth`, not `/oauth2`. It is essential that you have a unique `redirect_uri` for each oauth client, so you are not vulnerable to attacks such as mix-up (see our [SpringOne 2021 presentation](https://youtu.be/ZIjqDIdFyBw?t=1314) for more on this).

As the docs state, you'll also need a property to set your client registration to match:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.abc-auth.redirect-uri={baseUrl}/oauth2/{registrationId}
```